# db2 programming

Tags: mysql, plsql, db2

I'm currently porting a MySql database to DB2. So far, I've been able to migrate the tables, but unfortunately the functions and the triggers need to be manually migrated. I've read about pl/sql for DB2, but it isn't supported in the express-c version of DB2. Are there any alternatives on how i can convert mysql functions and triggers to DB2?

Comment: u can try a trail of this tool http://www.ispirer.com/products/db2-migration

Answer (score 5):

I think you are confusing PL/SQL (an Oracle compatibility layer) with SQL PL, a procedural language built into all editions of DB2, including [DB2 Express-C](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/download.html?S_CMP=ECDDWW01&S_TACT=LPSTACK).

You can, in fact, define [stored procedures](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008329.html), [functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000917.html), and [triggers](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html) in DB2 Express-C. There should be some info about it in the [Getting Started](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/DB2/FREE+Book-+Getting+Started+with+DB2+Express-C) e-book.

Comment: Actually DB2 9.7 *does* support Oracle's PL/SQL but not in the Express edition.

Comment: Leons is correct. PL/SQL compatibility is a relatively new feature in DB2, intended primarily to assist DBAs who are migrating off of Oracle. Triggers, procedures, and user-defined functions do not need to be written in PL/SQL, and are typically written in SQL PL, which has been part of DB2 for over a decade.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: All paid editions of DB2 have the Oracle compatibility layer right now, including DB2 Express. DB2 Express-C is the free edition.

Comment: Actually, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1311db2compare/index.html says that even Express-C (at least the latest version) includes PL/SQL.  "All DB2 editions have the DB2 compatibility feature set for Oracle, which includes PL/SQL, SQL*Plus, Oracle database concurrency, data types, and more. These capabilities help reduce the complexity of migrating Oracle applications to DB2."

Answer (score 0):

As long as you stay inside of the SQL-92 standard you will have  no problems - otherwise - you will have to create a few procedures to enhance compatibility I did one for BIT_XOR:

```
CREATE FUNCTION BITAND (N1 Integer, N2 Integer)
RETURNS Integer
SPECIFIC BITANDMySQL
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN
WITH
Repeat (S, M1, M2, Ans) AS
(Values (0, N1, N2, 0)
Union All
Select S+1, M1/2, M2/2, Ans+MOD(M1,2)*MOD(M2,2)*power(2,S)
From Repeat
Where M1 > 0
AND M2 > 0
AND S < 32
)
SELECT ANS
FROM Repeat
WHERE S = (SELECT MAX(S)
FROM Repeat)
;
```